# How to display 3 items per row in flexbox?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a list and I want to display my `li` elements horizontally and 3 per row. I've been trying to get what I want, but no luck. Is there a solution?

```
<div class="serv">
  <ul>                                             
    @foreach(App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::getservice($service->id) as 
    $key => $value)
    <li>
      <span class="h3-service">{{$value->title}}</span>
      <p>{!!$value->description!!}</p>
    </li>
    @endforeach
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

```
.serv ul {
  display: inline-flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 33%;
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
}
.serv ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
}
.serv ul li span {
  padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 195, accepted):

For the flex container:

- You probably want to use `display: flex;` not `inline-flex`.
- Add `flex-wrap: wrap;` to allow items to wrap when needed.
- Remove `width: 33%;` so it takes entire space available.

For 3 items per row, add these to the flex items:

- `flex-grow: 0;` + `flex-shrink: 0;` + `flex-basis: 33.3333%;`
- Or use the shorthand `flex: 0 0 33.3333%;`

```css
.serv ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.serv li {
  flex: 0 0 33.3333%;
  outline: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="serv">
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

To add `gap` to flexbox, see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72116170/483779).

But, it's a lot easier to use CSS grid instead:

```css
.serv ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(0, 1fr));
  gap: 20px;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.serv li {
  outline: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="serv">
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: How to combine that with flex gap. It seems to break if the item has a gap: 1em or any other value applied and only two are shown per row.

Comment: @BenjaminK for padding add box-sizing: border-box to li, for margin say 1em change it to flex: 0 0 calc(33.333333% - 2em).

Comment: how to combine gap and flex-basis ?

Comment: @SaeedArianmanesh added info for gap in flexbox and grid

Answer (score 4):

I had this same issue, but the selected correct answer did not work cause the my **child items** needed to have a *fix width* so here is my solution to show X items of fix width on **DISPLAY: FLEX**.

```
// Flex item width required: 215px
// Flex item margin 20px on each side: 215px + 20 + 20 = 255px
// I needed 3(your item per row) so: 255px * 3
// Then to (100% of parent-flex minus 255 * 3) / 2 padding on each side
// So it stays in the center.
padding: 40px calc((100% - (255px * 3)) / 2);
```

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parent-flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: tomato;
  padding: 40px calc((100% - (255px * 3)) / 2);
}

.flex-item {
   height: 100px;
   flex: 0 0 215px;
   margin: 1em 20px;
   border: 2px blue solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-flex">
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: In desktop, which is when I need them with specific size not bigger than that.

Comment: @TemaniAfif you  were right, I did not have 3 elements, the reason was the border I added to see the parent container, now I have changed it for background and 3 elements are shown per row.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
.flex-item{
   /* 
   All you need to do this play with this number (343) according to aviable width and item width 
   Formula: (ParentWidth / 3) - margin (ParentWidth divide by 3 subtracte by margin[if you want e.g in my case i set 10] )
   
   Stackoverflow Run Code Snippet width = 633.82px (not sure)
   Margin = 10px
   
   */
   flex: 0 0 192px; /* play with this number */
   background: red;
   margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="flex-item">1</div>
  <div class="flex-item">2</div>
  <div class="flex-item">3</div>
  <div class="flex-item">4</div>
  <div class="flex-item">5</div>
  <div class="flex-item">6</div>
  <div class="flex-item">7</div>
  <div class="flex-item">8</div>
  <div class="flex-item">9</div>
  <div class="flex-item">10</div>
</div>
```