# Using Flex/CSS with wkhtmltopdf

Tags: html, css, pdf

I've successfully created a list using the following answer with flexbox on my HTML page [How to display 3 items per row in flexbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48464444/how-to-display-3-items-per-row-in-flexbox)

I have a need to create a PDF with this data and I'm using wkhtmltopdf (https://wkhtmltopdf.org/) which also works fine however the PDF generated has all my List Items in 1 long column instead of 3 per row.

Looks like the CSS is not being processed when the PDF generation is happening any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

This worked for me :

```
.row {
    display: -webkit-box; /* wkhtmltopdf uses this one */
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center; /* wkhtmltopdf uses this one */
    justify-content: center;
}

.row > div {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
}

.row > div:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

See https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/1522 for more informations.

Comment: Good call!  `webkit-box` was the missing component that I couldn't figure out.

Comment: This is worked for me too!

Comment: While this is a solution, it isn't by far the solution. webkit-box is not even close to flex. Hope wkhtmltopdf accepts flex soon, but I really doubt about that since flex been out since 2013 :(

Comment: @Bengala - wkhtmltopdf uses the original QtWebKit, which is abandoned.  The developers have asked for help moving to something newer, but there have not been enough/any volunteers.  See wkhtmltopdf.org/status.html for the full story.

Answer (score 11):

I resolved this issue using:

equivalent of `display:flex;` ==> `display: -webkit-box;`

equivalent of `justify-content: space-between;` ==> `-webkit-box-pack: justify;`

Some useful informations coming from:
https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/1522

Answer (score 5):

As fix for Bootstrap 5, working with wkhtmltopdf 0.12.*, I found and completed the following style

```
            <style>
                /* Fix wkhtmltopdf compatibility with BS flex features */

                .row {
                    display: -webkit-box;
                    display: flex;
                    -webkit-box-pack: center;
                    justify-content: center;
                }

                .row>div {
                    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
                    -webkit-flex: 1;
                    flex: 1;
                }

                .row>div:last-child {
                    margin-right: 0;
                }


                /* Fix wkhtmltopdf compatibility with BS tables borders */


                /* Requires cellspacing="0" on table to prevent spacing */

                table {
                    border-collapse: separate !important;
                }

                th,
                td {
                    border-top: none;
                    border-left: none;
                    border-right: none;
                }

            </style>
```

[source](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/4792#issuecomment-906129609) saved my day while upgrading from bs 4 to bs 5.

Comment: Thank you SO much, I've been going crazy over this!

Answer (score 4):

I used autoprefixer in my application to automatically add prefixes. You just need to update `browsersList` with `ie >= 9`.

Answer (score 2):

Try to decrease the width of the flex columns. For example when I tried to make 50/50 columns I had to put a width of 49.8% instead of 50%. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

To use flex or boxes while converting to pdf, You need webkit
Example:-

```
display: flex;
display: -webkit-flex;
```

for justify-content and align items you have to use

```
-webkit-align-self: flex-end;
 align-self: flex-end;
webkit-justify-content: space-between;
justify-content: space-between;
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
.row {
  white-space: nowrap;
  > div {
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: normal;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can render only two image for multiple rows

```css
       .img-item {
            border: 1px solid #4a4a4a;
            display: inline-block;
            width:48%;
            margin: 5px;
        }
```