# Odoo QWeb - Flexbox not working when create pdf report

Tags: flexbox, odoo, qweb

When this below code is used in HTML and opened using a browser, the flexbox effects are what I want. But when I use the same code in QWeb, the output is different (the flex div is not divided into two sections).

```
<div style="display: flex;">
    <div style="border: 1px solid #ccc; flex: 1;">
        <p>Lorem</p>
        <p>Ipsum</p>
        <p>Dolor</p>
    </div>
    <div style="border: 1px solid #ccc; flex: 1;">
        <p>Lorem</p>
        <p>Ipsum</p>
        <p>Dolor</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Browser

[image]

PDF Report

[image]

Comment: In qweb, use div class ='float-left col-6' and float-right

Comment: But I want to use flexbox instead because I don't just want to split the page into 2 sections.

Comment: As my experience, display:flex is not worked in qweb.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not qweb but wkhtmltopdf. You can try webkit-box as mentioned in [Using Flex/CSS with wkhtmltopdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57020675/using-flex-css-with-wkhtmltopdf)

```
<div style="display: flex; display: -webkit-box; -webkit-box-pack: center; justify-content: center;">
    <div style="border: 1px solid #ccc; flex: 1; -webkit-box-flex: 1; -webkit-flex: 1;">
        <p>Lorem</p>
        <p>Ipsum</p>
        <p>Dolor</p>
    </div>
    <div style="border: 1px solid #ccc; flex: 1; -webkit-box-flex: 1; -webkit-flex: 1; margin-right: 0;">
        <p>Lorem</p>
        <p>Ipsum</p>
        <p>Dolor</p>
    </div>
</div>
```