# wkhtmltopdf equivalent of flex with -webkit-box

Tags: css, flexbox, wkhtmltopdf, phpwkhtmltopdf

I'm having hard times with wkhtmltopdf.
I use the binary version 0.12.

my html version is like this

```
   // container
   <div name="container" style="display:flex;flex-flow:column;justify-content: flex-end;width:1000px;height:500px;left:10px;top:10px;background-color:yellow;">
        // content
        <h2>title</h2>
        <div style="flex-grow: 1; background-color:green;">
        // some content
        </div>   
    </div>
```

Massive problem : wkhtmltopdf doesn't work with `flex` or `-webkit-flex`

I saw on stackoverflow that the solution would be to use `display:-webkit-box` instead. Src : [Using Flex/CSS with wkhtmltopdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57020675/using-flex-css-with-wkhtmltopdf)
But that doesn't align the divs in column et create a result like this :
[example of the glitch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z75rv.png)

What is the proper way to vertically align divs in order to put the green content under the title while still fitting yellow container (and without using flex) ?