# How to display array of certain cards in rows and in each row I have to display 3 cards using react js?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am getting this cards by clicking a button. If I click the button one card will be displayed like that If I click 20 times 20 cards will be displayed side by side I want to display three cards in first row side by side and in second row another three cards side by side  how to do this?
Thanks in advance

AllTasks.js

```
class AllTasks extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = {
         modal: false,
         input: {},
         errors: {},
         startDate: new Date(),
         actualStartDate: '',
         username: '',
         email: '',
         cardOpen: false,
         sidebar: false,
         change: []
      };

      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
      this.dateChange = this.dateChange.bind(this);
      this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(e) {
        let input = this.state.input;
        input[e.target.name] = e.target.value;

        this.setState({
            input,
        })
    }

    showSidebar = () => {
        this.setState({
            sidebar: !this.state.sidebar
        })
    }

    dateChange(date) {
        let selectedDateFromCalender = date.toUTCString();
        this.setState({
            startDate: date,
            actualStartDate: selectedDateFromCalender
        });
    }

    validate(){
        let input = this.state.input;
        let errors = {};
        let isValid = true;

        //title
        if(!input['modalTitle']){
            isValid = false;
            errors['modalTitle'] = 'cannot be empty';
        } 

        //description
        if(!input['modalDescription']){
            isValid = false;
            errors['modalDescription'] = 'cannot be empty';
        } 

        this.setState({ errors: errors });
        return isValid;
    }

    handleSubmit = (e, element) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        localStorage.setItem('data',JSON.stringify(this.state.input));
        localStorage.setItem('date',JSON.stringify(this.state.actualStartDate));
        let components = this.state.change;

        element = <Card/>

        components.push(element);

        if(this.validate()){
            console.log(this.state);

            let input = {};
            input['modalTitle'] = '';
            input['modalDescription'] = '';
            input['modalImportance'] = ''
            this.setState({
                input: input,
                cardOpen: true,
                actualStartDate: this.state.actualStartDate,
                change: components
            });

            this.modalClose();
        }       
    }

    modalOpen(){
        this.setState({
            modal: true
        });
    }

    modalClose(){
        this.setState({
            modal: false
        })
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <>
                <Navbar />
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-2">
                            
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-sm-8">
                            <h1>All Tasks</h1>
                        </div>
                        <button type="button" className="btn col-sm-2" onClick={e => this.modalOpen(e)}><h5>+ New Task</h5></button>
                    </div>
                </div>  
                <div className='popup'> 
                    <Modal show={this.state.modal} handleClose={e => this.modalClose(e)}>

                        <div className="form-group">

                            <h5>Title</h5>

                            <input 
                                type="text" 
                                name='modalTitle'
                                value={this.state.input.modalTitle}
                                onChange={this.handleChange}
                                className="form-control"
                                placeholder="What needs to be done ?"
                                required
                            />
                            <span style={{color: 'red'}}>{this.state.errors['modalTitle']}</span>

                            <h5>Description</h5>

                            <textarea 
                                type="text" 
                                name='modalDescription'
                                value={this.state.input.modalDescription}
                                onChange={this.handleChange}
                                className="form-control"
                                placeholder="Description"
                                rows="4" 
                                cols="20"
                                maxlength = "80"
                                required
                            />
                            <span style={{color: 'red'}}>{this.state.errors['modalDescription']}</span>

                            <h5>Date Picker</h5>

                            <DatePicker
                                className="datePicker"
                                type="date"
                                name="modalDate"
                                selected={this.state.startDate}
                                onChange={this.dateChange}
                                dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"
                            />

                            <h5>Importance</h5>
                            
                            <div className="selected">
                                <select className="form-control" id="exampleSelect1" name='modalImportance' onChange={this.handleChange}>
                                    <option>Low</option>
                                    <option>Medium</option>
                                    <option>High</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div className="form-group">
                            <button className="modalButton" type="button" onClick={e => this.handleSubmit(e)}>
                                    Add New Task
                            </button>
                        </div>

                    </Modal>
                </div> 
            {this.state.cardOpen ?  
                <div className="cards">
                    {this.state.change.map(comp => (comp))}
                </div> 
            : null}
            </>
        );
    }
}

export default AllTasks;
```

Cards.js

```
class Card extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
          cardDelete: false
        }
    }

    delete(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
           cardDelete: true
        })
    }

    render(){
        const result = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data'));
        const selectedDate = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('date'));
        const actualDate = selectedDate.split("",17);
        return(
            <>
            {result ?
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="col">
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-2">
                            
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-sm-5">
                                <div className="card">
                                    <div className="card-body">
                                        <div className="delete" onClick={this.delete}>
                                        <AiIcons.AiTwotoneDelete/>
                                        </div>
                                        <h5 className="card-title">{result.modalTitle </h5>
                                        <p className="card-text" {result.modalDescription}</p>
                                        <div className="row">
                                            <h5 className="card-text icon">
                                                <AiIcons.AiOutlineFieldTime/> {actualDate} 
                                            </h5>
                                            <div className="flag">
                                                <AiIcons.AiFillFlag/>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-5">

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div> : null }
            </>
        );
    }
}

export default Card;
```

AllTasks.css

```
.container h1{
    color: #03015d;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.container .btn{
    font-family: "Poppins",sans-serif;
    width: 20vw;
    padding: 1.8vh 15px;
    border: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
    border-radius: 7px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    background-color: #03015d;
    color: #fff;
}

.container {
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.modal {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.popup h5{
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.popup  input {
    font-family: "Poppins",sans-serif;
    width: 20vw;
    padding: 1.8vh 15px;
    border: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
    border-radius: 7px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.popup textarea {
    font-family: "Poppins",sans-serif;
    width: 20vw;
    padding: 1.8vh 15px;
    border: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
    border-radius: 7px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.popup .datePicker {
    width: 10vw;
    padding: 1.8vh 15px;
    border: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
    border-radius: 7px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.selected {
    width: 10vw;
    border: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
    border-radius: 7px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.popup .modalButton {
    font-family: "Poppins",sans-serif;
    width: 20vw;
    padding: 1.8vh 15px;
    border: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
    border-radius: 7px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    background-color: #03015d;
    color: #fff;
}

.cards {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
```

Card.css

```
.card {
    width: 18rem;
    height: 13rem;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.card-title {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.icon {
    font-size: 20px;
    /* font-weight: bold; */
}

.delete{
    float: right;
    font-size: 25px;
}

.flag{
    font-size: 23px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.sideItems{
    padding: 10px 10px 10px;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48464444/how-to-display-3-items-per-row-in-flexbox/48464559 . This should give you an idea .

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using css/scss.

1. make size of card and card-container such that the container fits only 3 three cards.
2. make card container as flex. and use `flex-wrap: wrap;`
3. this should wrap cards after 3rd card to new line