# Account for gap when calculating flex-basis

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I'm trying to use `gap` to specify gaps between flexed items within my grid system, but running in to a major drawback. It seems that when you're using `flex-grow: 0;`/`flex-shrink: 0;` in conjunction with `gap` and `flex-basis` values that fill the entire available width (i.e. three columns with `flex: 0 0 33.3333%;`), the columns overflow their parent container as the `gap` doesn't account for the fixed width as specified with `flex: 0 0 33.3333%`.

Similar to `box-sizing: border-box;`, is there some way to instruct the rendering engine that the gap should be subtracted when determining the width of these columns?

**Demonstration:**

```css
.row {
    display: flex;
    gap: 30px;
    border: 2px solid red;
}

.col {
    flex: 0 0 33.3333%;
    background: teal;
    border: 2px solid #004D4D;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}

:root {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<h2>With gap:</h2>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        1
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        2
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        3
    </div>
</div>

<h2>Without gap:</h2>

<div class="row" style="gap:0;">
    <div class="col">
        1
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        2
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        3
    </div>
</div>
```

*Note:* I *could* account for this with a formula like `flex-basis: calc($width - ($gap / ($number-of-columns / 2));`, but as this is for a reusable grid system, I can't practically account for every possible scenario.

Comment: Not yet AFAIK...`gap` isn't really that useful in flexbox IMO.

Comment: Yeah, that's been my experience too. A lot of promise, a lot of problems.

Comment: Well written problem definition! I stumbled upon that problem today. To extend on my use case: I have a mini flex grid system using wrap to make it multi-line. There can be different container sizes in it and it should not need to know about the containers filling it up.

Comment: In practice, that `padding: 50px;` coupled with the use of `gap: 0;` would create the spacing with the content still wrapping in the flexbox; that's my approach in order to avoid complicated CSS calculations as the provided answers

Answer (score 19):

The formula you mentioned works... You can use CSS variables to make a reusable grid system. A buddy and I came up with this:

```
.flex {
  --cols: 3;
  --gap: 30px;
  display: flex;
  gap: var(--gap);
}

.flex-child {
  flex-basis: calc(100% / var(--cols) - var(--gap) / var(--cols) * (var(--cols) - 1));
}

@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  .flex{
    --cols: 2;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 750px) {
  .flex{
    --cols:1;
  }
}
```

So then all you need to change are the variables `--cols` and `--gap`
https://codepen.io/pyledigital/pen/mdWmjQb

Comment: Works! But you only need one wrapping calc, not the inner ones. Example if you only have --cols as a var:


`flex-basis: calc((100% / var(--cols)) - (3rem / var(--cols) * (var(--cols) - 1)));`

Comment: Love this, with @NicolasA.T. 's addition (subtraction?) to reduce complexity

Comment: I use a very similar formula but with default variable values in case something isn't set: `calc((100% / var(--cols, 1)) - (((var(--cols, 1) - 1) * var(--gap, 0)) / var(--cols, 1)))`. Combined with a SASS mixin to define gap & cols for different breakpoints in different scenarios, this has proven to be very powerful. It's unfortunate that flex doesn't take gap into account - would be far simpler to just define a width of, say, 25% and have the gap subtracted automatically.

Answer (score 4):

Here is another not very elegant quick way to hack your way forward. Similar to the answer by UPinar it alters the outer flex container. Here with negative margin on the right (this might cause other layout problems!). This "solution" is using shrink 0. Also it works with a wrapping flex.

I agree that this should not be so complicated and hacky. Maybe we are missing something? I am also under the impression that this is not the really the desired box-sizing border-box behavior which I hoped to find in combination with the `gap` property.

`flex` and `gap` should be hack free like: Draw three containers each consuming a third of the width and have some space between em. AFAIK gap works that way with CSS grid and CSS columns.

```css
.flex {
    display: flex;
    flex-grow: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.flex.gap {
   gap: var(--space-s);
   margin-right: calc(-1 * var(--space-s));
}

.col {
    flex-basis: 33.3333%;
    background: teal;
    border: 2px solid #004D4D;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}

.flex.gap .col {
    flex-basis: calc(33.3333% - var(--space-s));
    background: teal;
    border: 2px solid #004D4D;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}

:root {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    --space-s: 1rem;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<h2>With gap</h2>

<div class="flex gap">
    <div class="col">
        1
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        2
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        3
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        4
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        5
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        6
    </div>
</div>

<h2>Without gap</h2>

<div class="flex">
    <div class="col">
        1
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        2
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        3
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        4
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        5
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        6
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This answer is on to something. It was the only way I could solve this problem in the context where I was having it, which was for a generic column layout solution, so I could not rely on knowing the number of flex items in advance. Furthermore, I was able to even get rid of the need to use margins entirely. The trick is to not subtract the gap space from the last flex item, only doing it on the first n-1 items. More details in https://github.com/Doist/reactist/pull/739 (see commit titled "Fix columns issue").

Answer (score 3):

For this layout, consider Grid's flexibility over Flexbox.

See the demo:

```css
.row {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    gap: 30px;
    border: 2px solid red;
}

.col {
    background: teal;
    border: 2px solid #004D4D;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h2>With gap:</h2>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        1
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        2
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        3
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Grid is a lot more predictable in larger layouts using gap and fr units than flex is. But you have to use fr as the width measurement and not %, because % does not factor the gap, whereas fr calculates whatever is left over.

Answer (score 0):

When you add a `padding-right: calc(var(--gap-space) * 2);` to parent container. Parent container width will calculte before child containers use `100%` which is parent container width. You need to change parent containers width before using its width inside child container.

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  text-rendering: optimizeSpeed;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: bisque;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
}


:root{
  --gap-space:30px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}


.row-1 {
  display: flex;
  gap: var(--gap-space);
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding-right: calc(var(--gap-space) * 2);

}

.row-1 .col{
  background: teal;
  border: 2px solid #004D4D;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  flex: 0 0 calc(100% / 3);
}

.row-2{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.row-2 .col{
  background: teal;
  border: 2px solid #004D4D;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  flex: 0 0 calc(100% / 3);
}
```

```html
<h2>With gap:</h2>

    <div class="row-1">
      <div class="col">1</div>
      <div class="col">2</div>
      <div class="col">3</div>
    </div>

    <h2>Without gap:</h2>

    <div class="row-2" style="gap: 0">
      <div class="col">1</div>
      <div class="col">2</div>
      <div class="col">3</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: While `flex-shrink: 1;` would work in some circumstances, I often need to use `flex-shrink: 0;` to ensure sizing is correct. For one example, sometimes I'll have one column with `flex: 1 1 0%;` and another with `flex: 0 0 33.3333%;` which is effectively two thirds and one third, but using `flex: 1 1 33.3333%;` on the one third column in this case would cause it to display larger than `33.3333%` of the total width.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with using only width?

```css
.col {
    width: 33.3333%;
  ...
}
```

```css
.row {
    display: flex;
    gap: 30px;
    border: 2px solid red;
}

.col {
    width: 33.3333%;
    background: teal;
    border: 2px solid #004D4D;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}

:root {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<h2>With gap:</h2>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        1
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        2
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        3
    </div>
</div>

<h2>Without gap:</h2>

<div class="row" style="gap:0;">
    <div class="col">
        1
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        2
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        3
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works if you just want one row, but if you want the row to wrap when there are more than 3 items, this does not work - the same problem as outlined above occurs.

Comment: Indeed, it works only for one row. I still think it's great, because those are common cases (e.g. when you can to build a generic multi-column layout component).

However, this has other drawback. It does not yield consistent widths of columns. For instance, in a 1/3 + 1/3 + 1/3 layout, the first column won't have the same width as the first column in the layout 1/3 + 2/3. See https://github.com/Doist/reactist/pull/739#issuecomment-1373825792 for details.